# Why is my equation for getting the energy of a capacitor wrong?

Tags: capacitor, energy

I have a question.

Because \$Q=CV\$, \$U=VIt\$ and \$Q=It\$

The energy in joules of a capacitor from what I get is
\$U=QV\$ with \$U=C(V^2)\$

But why when I see on the internet it is \$U=(C/2)(V^2)\$ ?

Correct me if i'm wrong at the equation please.

Comment: What is U and what is V in your equations? Ah, I think U is energy? Better use E as U is also used for voltage.

Comment: @Huisman U is energy in joules, V is voltage

Comment: It's because you are really integrating: \$\int \$

Comment: @jonk I don't understand

Comment: Sorry. I'll write more. My cell phone app posted the response too early. Forgive me that mistake. But for now, yes. This is an integral equation and that's the reason for the one-half factor.

Comment: See [this site](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html#c2).

Comment: BTW, \$U=VIt\$ is also only *sometimes* true. The real definition is \$ U=\int{V(t) \cdot I(t) } dt\$ When V and I are constant, it simplifies to  \$U=VIt\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one very importent fact: The discharged capacitor has **zero** volts.

On other words: Voltage is not a constant, but a linear function. That is where the integrale (thanks @jonk) originates.

So the "real" formular is `U=∫CV` which yields `U=1/2 * C * V²` after integration.